Drywall to bathroom floor ditra gap
I have about 1 1/2" gap between the drywall and Ditra because two pieces 4'x8' drywall board leaves quite a bit of a gap in the bottom. I didn't think it makes sense to cut a thin strip of drywall to fill the gap because there will be a baseboard. But I have a couple of debates:
If I should add the schluter membrane in the whole bathroom along the gap. I only have a bathtub so the only place that could have leak is around the toilet.
If it makes sense to have the membrane, should I add 3/4" strip of drywall to reduce the gap to 3/4" between wall edge and dDitra (will finish at about 1/4-3/8" drywall and tile). I think 3/4" of gap should be fine to hold the Schluter membrane.


what is the wall been covered with

This question hasn't gotten many answers because it is an odd situation.
First it isn't normal to put schluter on the floor unless you are making a wetroom. You didn't say you are doing that.
If you think the only place water will be and issue is the tub, then just add your baseboard when the walls and the floor are done and call it a day. (I usually caulk the bottom of the baseboard to the floor in a bathroom.)
If the plan is a wet room, the schluter should have gone from the floor up the wall about 6 inches. You don't have that either.
At this point I think it is useless to add any schluter to the bottom of the walls.

Oh thank you.  Yea it’s not a wet room.  The only reason with the ditra is for the floor thickness.  Sites is thinner than other materials such as durock.  Thank you so much for the response
